# Cocos2d FPS drops || works only in  profiling mode

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, profiling, physics, box2d

I'm just building a small Cocos2d test game with a few physics obstacles which
the player (a circle) can ram.
Everything works fine on Simulator (60 FPS) but on device I get only 17 FPS.
The funny thing is - If I use the profiling mode (e.g. activity monitor) I get
55-60 FPS on device. What's going on there?

Answer (score 0):

First, disregard the iOS Simulator performance entirely. For one, it can be significantly faster because the Intel CPU of a Mac computer is a lot faster than the ARM CPUs on iOS Devices. On the other hand, the iOS Simulator does not take advantage of graphics acceleration, it uses a software renderer. So graphics performance can be significantly slower than that of an iOS device, and it is not in the least bit comparable to real device performance and can not be used to make assertions like "but it runs fast on iOS Simulator". That simply has no relevance.

I don't know how [Activity Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_Monitor) would affect your device performance. It has nothing to do with measuring or profiling the device performance. The tool for measuring device performance is [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) that comes with Xcode. You can also use the [CCProfiler](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_profiler.html) class provided by cocos2d-iphone.

General tips for physics engines on iOS is to reduce the number of iterations. You can often get away with a much lower number of iterations, which reduces the CPU load.